# Using moment.js Timezone to set starting timezone and converting to other timezones

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm following an example from https://www.alex-arriaga.com/how-to-set-moment-js-timezone-when-creating-a-date/ but not getting the results I'm expecting. My startDateAndTimeString has the time set to 08:00 and I set the timezone to Mexico_City which is in CST. Then I'm trying to convert to New_York (EST) and Los_Angeles (PST) time.

I would expect if the starting time is 08:00 CST then it would be 09:00 EST and 06:00 PST but I'm seeing 05:00 PST and 08:00 EST. Locally, I'm in EST which would make sense if I wasn't setting the starting time to CST. Can I not set the starting time to CST when I'm in EST ?

```js
var startDateAndTimeString = '2023-03-05 08:00:00';

// CST
var startDateAndTime = moment(startDateAndTimeString).tz('America/Mexico_City');

function formatDateToAnotherTimezone(anotherTimezone, startDateAndTime) {
 return moment(startDateAndTime).tz(anotherTimezone).format('ha z');
}


var est = formatDateToAnotherTimezone('America/New_York',startDateAndTime);
var pst = formatDateToAnotherTimezone('America/Los_Angeles',startDateAndTime);

console.log(est)
console.log(pst)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I think that is not the correct way to use moment.tz

To make it easier, I am printing out the GMT time represented by `startDateAndTime` in the Mexico timezone.

You can see that the first `console.log` prints the wrong answer.

But when we call moment.tz correctly, the second `console.log` prints the right answer.

The subsequent adjustments use the correct value of `startDateAndTime`.

```js
var startDateAndTimeString = '2023-03-05 08:00:00';

// CST
var wrongStartDateAndTime = moment(startDateAndTimeString).tz('America/Mexico_City');
console.log("wrongStartDateAndTime",wrongStartDateAndTime)

startDateAndTime = moment.tz(startDateAndTimeString,'America/Mexico_City');
console.log("When we instead use moment.tz correctly:")
console.log("startDateAndTime",startDateAndTime)


function formatDateToAnotherTimezone(anotherTimezone, startDateAndTime) {
  return moment(startDateAndTime).tz(anotherTimezone).format('ha z');
}


var est = formatDateToAnotherTimezone('America/New_York', startDateAndTime);
var pst = formatDateToAnotherTimezone('America/Los_Angeles', startDateAndTime);

console.log(est)
console.log(pst)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```